# Speed up numerical integration in Cython

Tags: python, performance, cython

As part of a physics calculation, I load a list of electrical field values from a csv file, and pass them to a Cython function for integration.  This is not a simple summation of the values in the file, but requires a recalculation of a certain parameter at each step of the integration.  By reorganising the code, and moving the slowest parts to Cython, I have achieved a significant boost in speed, however I suspect there are further optimisations that could be done.

Here is the Cython function that I am trying to speed up:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
cdef float m = 938272046
cdef float c = 299792458
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def ELTintegration(float xelmax, float deltaT, float phi, float omega, 
                np.ndarray[DTYPE_t] zExtract, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t] EzExtract, float KEin):
    cdef float integ = 0 
    cdef float xelmax_deltaT = xelmax * deltaT
    cdef unsigned int i, loopLen=len(EzExtract)
    cdef float v
    cdef float z, Ez, phaseTerm, diff
    cdef float newE, gamma, beta
    for i in range(len(EzExtract)):
        z = zExtract[i]
        Ez = EzExtract[i]
        newE = KEin + integ
        gamma = newE/m + 1 
        beta = (1 - 1/gamma**2)**0.5
        v = beta * c 
        phaseTerm = np.cos(omega*z/v + phi)
        diff = phaseTerm * Ez * xelmax_deltaT
        integ = integ + diff

    return integ
```

Each of the ndarrays is one dimensional, and contains ~4000 floats.

As you can see, I have declared all variables I use, switched off bounds checking, made the array indexing efficient, and pulled all necessary calculations out of the loop.

Have I reached the limit of what I can reasonably do to speed this up?  Is there anything I have missed in terms of achieving a more efficient function?  Is it realistic to think I could speed this up by another factor of 2?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think this might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com since your code is working and you're asking for ways to improve it. StackOverflow is more set on fixing bugs/getting a program to run at all.

Comment: Have you tried running your project in PyPy? It's especially well suited for the kind of algorithmic-like things you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the PyPy recommendation.  I'll have a look at it.  At the moment (after using Veedrac's suggestions), I have optimised the code as well as I need to for now, but PyPy could be a good tool for future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Pietzcker is right that it's better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but it's also almost on-topic here, so I'll go for it.

If you run

```
cython -a myfile.pyx
```

You will see yellow. Often, but not always, yellow means slow. The most important yellow is with the `np.cos` call. This will be extremely slow because you're going through Python and doing lots of type creation to get it done.

Using

```
from libc.math cimport cos
```

will let you use C's `cos`, which will be much faster.

There are also some checks for division by zero and the sign of division. These are avoidable by turning the [compiler directive](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives) `cdivision` to `True`.

Note that the modern way of using Numpy arrays is with the memoryview syntax (eg. `DTYPE_t[:]` for a 1D memoryview of type `DTYPE_t`).

Also note that you might be as good off or even better off using `numba` and `autojit` on the plain Python code. `numba` does crazy things.

Comment: Wow.  I gained an order of magnitude just from the use of libc's cosine!  Incredible.
Now the performance bottlenecks in the other parts of my project are the real issue, and I think that this function is as well optimised as needed.  Many thanks for your help, and thanks for pointing out that I should have used Code Review.

Comment: I tried to upvote the answer, but lack sufficient reputation points. But I accepted this as the answer I needed.